# Is there a way to create a Firestore Document using currentUser uid

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I am trying to use Angular and Firebase to set up a frontend back end relationship in the simplest way. i need when a user is logged in that the users information gets pushed to Firestore. I get the token pushed but the users data stops the pipeline and nothing gets pushed.

" firebase.auth().currentUser " to add data to a Firestore collection, but everytime i try the  app seems to not push any data.

```js
import {
  Component
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  AngularFireMessaging
} from '@angular/fire/messaging';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
import {
  filter
} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {
  mergeMapTo
} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {
  mergeMap
} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {
  AngularFireAuth
} from '@angular/fire/auth';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import {
  AngularFirestore,
  AngularFirestoreCollection
} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import {
  Observable
} from 'rxjs';
import {
  switchMap
} from 'rxjs/operators';

export class AppComponent {

  private user = firebase.auth().currentUser

  constructor(private afMessaging: AngularFireMessaging, public auth: AngularFireAuth, private afs: AngularFirestore) {}
  requestPermission() {
    this.afMessaging.requestPermission
      .pipe(mergeMapTo(this.afMessaging.tokenChanges))
      .subscribe(
        (token) => {
          this.afs.collection('users').add({
            fcmtoken: token,
            userid: user.uid
          })
        },
        (error) => {
          console.error(error);
        },
      );

  }


  listen() {
    this.afMessaging.messages
      .subscribe((message) => {
        console.log(message);
      });
  }

  deleteToken() {
    this.afMessaging.getToken
      .pipe(mergeMap(token => this.afMessaging.deleteToken(token)))
      .subscribe(
        (token) => {
          console.log('Token Has Been Deleted, Get a New One');
        },
      );
  }





  login() {
    this.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());

  }
  logout() {
    this.auth.signOut();
  }



}
```

The problem comes in here

```js
requestPermission() {
  this.afMessaging.requestPermission
    .pipe(mergeMapTo(this.afMessaging.tokenChanges))
    .subscribe(
      (token) => {
        this.afs.collection('users').add({
          fcmtoken: token,

          //if i remove this - all works well. the token is pushed//
          userid: user.uid

          //
        })
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error(error);
      },
    );

}
```

How do i take this code and create a system where a new document is created for every user and that document holds the used data, including the tokens.

Answer (score 0):

maybe... user is invalid, your code doesn't work.

```
requestPermission(user: User) { // (1) give a valid user.
  this.afMessaging.requestPermission
    .pipe(mergeMapTo(this.afMessaging.tokenChanges))
    .subscribe(
      (token: string | null) => { // (2) this can be null.
        if (!token) { // (3) add validation.
          return
        }
        this.afs.collection('users').add({
          fcmtoken: token,

          // (4) this will work.
          userid: user.uid

          //
        })
      },
      (error: any) => {
        console.error(error);
      },
    );

}
```